# Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint with Identity(1,1)

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have been struggling with a non-consistent issue for a while, and am hoping to get this figured out. At random times my system will have a group of 4-5 INSERTS that fail due to:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Quality_Checks'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Quality_Checks'. The duplicate key value is (25943).

Most other questions I have read for this error involve using something other than an `Identity(1,1)` as the PK, or very specialized situations, so I am posting my own issue.

I am using Entity Framework to work with my SQL Server 2012 database. I parse an XML file to a object called `Test_Run` then convert that object to my Entity objects to add to the table.

All tables use an `Identity(1,1)` as their primary key.

My conversion code:

```
public static int SaveTestRun(TestRun testRun)
{
        gReportEntities gReportEntity = new gReportEntities();
        var testRunTable = new Test_Runs()
        {
            TRX_Name = testRun.TrxFile,
            Start_Time = testRun.StartTime,
            Enviroment = testRun.Environment,
            Mach_Config = testRun.MachineConfiguration,
            Product = testRun.Product,
            Details = testRun.Details,
            Duration = testRun.Duration.ToString(),
            End_Time = testRun.EndTime,
            Failed_Num = testRun.FailedTestCount,
            Passed_Num = testRun.PassedTestCount,
            Incom_Num = testRun.IncompleteTestCount,
            Abort_Num = testRun.AbortedTestCount,
            NotEx_Num = testRun.NotExecutedTestCount,
            Timed_Num = testRun.TimedOutTestCount,
            QC_Failed_Num = testRun.FailedQualityChecksCount,
            QC_Passed_Num = testRun.PassedQualityChecksCount,
            QC_Incon_Num = testRun.InconclusiveQualityChecksCount,
            Video_Dir = testRun.VideoRootPath,
            Custom_Html = testRun.CustomHtml

        };

        foreach (var test in testRun.Tests)
        {
            var testResult = new Test_Results()
            {
                Test_Class = test.Value.TestClass,
                Test_Name = test.Value.Name,
                Result = test.Value.Outcome.ToString(),
                Start_Time = test.Value.StartDate,
                Guid = test.Value.Id,
                Duration = test.Value.Duration.ToString(),
                Category = String.Join(", ", test.Value.Categories),
                Error_Message = test.Value.ErrMessage,
                Stack_Trace = test.Value.StackTrace,
                Video_Link = test.Value.VideoPath,
                Comment = test.Value.Comment
            };

            foreach (var qCheck in test.Value.QualityChecks)
            {
                var qualityCheck = new Quality_Checks()
                {
                    Check_Name = qCheck.Name,
                    Check_Outcome = qCheck.Outcome.ToString(),
                    Message = qCheck.Message
                };
                testResult.Quality_Checks.Add(qualityCheck);
            }

            testRunTable.Test_Results.Add(testResult);
        }

        gReportEntity.Test_Runs.AddObject(testRunTable);

        gReportEntity.SaveChanges();

        return testRunTable.Test_Run_Id;
}
```

I need to get this issue fixed or my tool cannot be fully implemented.

Comment: What's the parent type of gReportEntities? Is it a DbContext?

Comment: @BrianKnight It is ObjectContext

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically if an identity column is violating a key constraint, it's because something got added to your table with an ID higher than the value that it's currently seeded at. So when you go to insert a new value, it finds that there's already an entry with that ID.

You'll probably want to [reseed your identity column](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/database/reset-identity-column-value-in-sql-server/).

Comment: Is there a way when SaveChanges() is called to check for a seeding issue or recover from a failure? Cause it does look like that might be the issue. It added a bunch of new rows, then tried to add the next INSERTs rows with a lower seed.

Comment: OK, my current Idea is to use
`DECLARE @currentIdentity INT;`
`SELECT @currentIdentity = MAX([Quality_Check_Id]) from [gReport].[dbo].[Quality_Checks];`
`DBCC CHECKIDENT ('[gReport].[dbo].[Quality_Checks]', reseed, @currentIdentity);`
`SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('[gReport].[dbo].[Quality_Checks]');`

Comment: @HauptmannEck: You should be allowing your identity columns to populate themselves; if you're not doing that, that's the root of the issue. I would seek out the source of the problem and fix that, rather than trying to make my code have to navigate around something that should never happen.

Comment: I do allow it to Populate the Identity Column itself.  About once a month the Identity does not update correctly causing the Primary Key error. I need to change something to guarantee the issue wont happen again.

Comment: @HauptmannEck: I've never heard of that happening by accident, and I'm pretty sure I'd have heard of it if it's something that SQL Server does from time to time. Is it possible that you've got some kind of script running once a month that creates identities explicitly using `identity_insert`?

Comment: It is a new issue for me as well, as it is a very basic setup with no odd scripts. luckily this server is being retired eventually, but for now I am thinking of having the code reseed the column and try the SaveChanges again if it ever errors again.